# Getting Text from UILabel on Tap

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm generating `UILabel`s programmatically and giving them each a tap gesture recognizer.

I'd like to access the text in each label when they are tapped.

You can see my code below. I've already looked through other answers and have tried to duplicate. But, I'm still getting a crash

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

whenever I try to tap the labels.

```
func placeLabelCenterish(){

    let pushedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,25))
    pushedLabel.center = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width)/2, 200)
    pushedLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    pushedLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
    pushedLabel.text = "HERE"
    self.view.addSubview(pushedLabel)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    tap.addTarget(self, action: "nameTap")
    pushedLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    pushedLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func nameTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("tapped")
    let thisLabel = sender.view as! UILabel
    print(thisLabel.text)
}
```

When I remove the sender : `UIGestureRecognizer` parameters from the second method, it prints "tapped" fine. So, I know it's receiving the tap.

```
func nameTap(){
    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: @dfri tried that and didn't work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change "*nameTap*" in `action` to "`nameTap:`" (note the colon); and `func nameTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer)` should be called upon tap.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. Damn colon.... I'll mark as answered in a few minutes.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Like I noted in my comment above, I fully intended to come back and mark as complete. The answer came very shortly after I posted my question (much appreciated) so I was locked out.